# What are good sources for the economics of patents?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, behavioral-macroeconomics

I am curious about how the stimuli patents exercise, upon innovation, may be counteracted by their slow down of the dissemination of technology. Reading suggestions will be very much appreciated.

My understanding is that the distinguished Norwegian neo classicist economist, Leif Johansen, was opposed to patents. His reasons may have had to do with the fact that he was a communist, and that he thought that patents exacerbated the distribution of wealth.